# Docker Builds Failing when running go get

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

All of my docker builds are getting this error when doing a go get.  Unfortunately the error message isn't very helpful (or I am struggling to understand it)...

```
Step 39/75 : RUN cd /go/src/${PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME}/ && go get ./...
 ---> Running in a36eb269a4dd
# golang.org/x/net/http2
../golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:417:45: undefined: os.ErrDeadlineExceeded
```

I turned on verbose in my go get and it wasn't that much more useful.   Any thoughts or ideas would be much appreciated:

```
go.opencensus.io/plugin/ochttp/propagation/b3
golang.org/x/xerrors
# golang.org/x/net/http2
../golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:417:45: undefined: os.ErrDeadlineExceeded
google.golang.org/api/googleapi/transport
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your `go` version is out of date, and the command `go get ./...` from `GOPATH/src` is not going to work for modern projects using modules. Update the project to use modules

Comment: This was it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I met with the same problem today.

Building following docker file gives that same error.

```
FROM golang:1.14-alpine as fuse
RUN apk add --no-cache git
ENV GOPATH /go
RUN go get -u github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse
```

Changing to this solves the problem.

```
FROM golang:1.17-alpine as fuse
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN go install github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse@v0.37.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I just remove the old docker images and generate a new one, then its working fine to me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31635335)